# Is swapping out the entire Left-Local-Side-Nav a bad idea?

Tags: navigation, menu, sidebar, mega-menu

We have a large Website with hundreds of pages.  We have a horizontal global navigation, and a left-local-side Nav to navigate through a group of related pages.

As I was browsing clicking down from the top to the lower links in the local Nav, one link **replaced the entire side nav with another group of side nav links".  I became lost and confused.  It took several seconds for me to realize what happened.

**Intuitively, I think the local side nav should never be swapped** with an internal click inside itself.

Is it just me, or is there some truth behind this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMX9P6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I hate sites with layout like this - so counter intuitive.

Comment: I'm blanking on a better title, but your real question doesn't entirely match your bolded question. The internal click is what's killer, not just switching local nav; of course local navs should be switched when "local" switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Before I address your actual question, I have to point out..**

I have seen this layout many times and it always annoys me - the problems I see with that layout are:

- Global menu takes you out of current site, yet appears to be a part of the site
- Site menu is in a different region of screen, making it confusing - which menu are you supposed to look at?
- Site menu is to the left of the content, thus taking your attention away from the content

I think that a more intuitive layout would be (from top to bottom):

- Global navigation at top most region of site (above logo) - as clicking on these links effectively take you to another site.
- Logo with customization for current site (e.g. company logo + a site element added to it)
- Site menu
- Content

**Now to your actual question:**

If clicking on a link opens a page/site with it own sub menu, I would use one of the following techniques:

- Expand its menu in place (e.g. with an accordion control or a tree menu (assuming menu is at the left))
- Add a sub menu under the current menu (assuming menu is at the top).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBRgln.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fccFLc.png)</sup>

Comment: Yes Danny, I totally agree.  This is a great solution to keep everything one side-nav.  That is what I want to do.  My problem is someone has already designed it... and it already exists the wrong way.  So, I am looking for supporting facts to show that swapping the side-nav is a shabby user experience.  I need facts and supporting information to back it up.  So far, I cannot find any.  But, thanks for the Implementation, I like it.

Comment: In that case, check out this book: http://www.sensible.com/rsme.html